# looking for answer of Ruby coding in linux

Tags: centos, ruby

puts ((11.to_s * 2).to_i/2), does anyone know answer of this coding? I am not aware of ruby!

Comment: This isn't  a proper question at all and, being programming related, off-topic anyway. Please read our [FAQ].

Comment: For your future reference this kind of question is better asked on stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

I just learned enough ruby to do this

```
ruby -e "puts ((11.to_s * 2).to_i/2)"
555
```

which doesn't help much

```
ruby -e "puts (11.to_s * 2)"
1111
```

So it appears to convert 11 to a string (`.to_s`) then doubles it then converts the answer back to an integer (`.to_i`) and then divides it by 2.